# Access token request sometimes gets stuck via Java SoundCloud API library

Tags: soundcloud

We have implemented a system to upload our MP3 podcasts to SoundCloud on a regular basis by using Java SoundCloud API library. Everything works great in 99% of the time.

However, we've had a couple of occasions when a worker thread, which runs periodically every couple of minutes, and whose job is to upload new podcasts (if any) simply gets "stuck" and never finishes the execution, although the code is wrapped with exception catching blocks, no exception ever gets thrown. This stops the execution of any consecutive such thread and the server has to be restarted in order to regain the functionality.

The code used for obtaining access token seems to be the only place where the problem can occur since we were not uploading a podcast at the time when the problems occurred.

When the problem happened we were asking for the token every time the job run (even though there were no podcasts to upload), so we changed that now so we ask for the token only when we upload a podcast (once a week) and it's less likely we will have the same situation again, but we were wondering is this something you've heard about before, and if there is something we can do to avoid this kind of situations? Thank you.

I'll be happy to provide any additional information, if needed.